# Authenticating in Azure but calling web api on localhost - 401

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile app authenticating on azure with FB and Twitter. I am able to login to both but when testing web api calls locally (hosted in IIS)  - any controller with the Authorize attribute - returns a 401.

The alternateLoginHost is set to the Azure host and it is providing me with a token after a successful login.

I followed the instructions in the docs about setting up Local debugging with authentication.

It is using attribute based routing - config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

Here is my full OWIN startup class

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authSigningKey"],
            ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authAudience"] },
            ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authIssuer"] },
            TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
        });

        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
```

I have seen references in the documentation about either using the global http config passed in from asp.net or creating a new one - I tried referencing the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration instead of creating a new instance but it didn't help.

Is there a way to hook into the OWIN pipeline to see if the token is making it to the app service authentication module?

[EDIT] **ZUMO AUTH HEADER**
I am also adding the x-zumo-auth header and setting it's value to the token from the current user like this

```
request.headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH',
app.azureClient.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken)
```

And I can see it in each request being made to the api. A call to the endpoint https://*mysite*.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me using this mechanism is returning a correct response so I know the token is valid.

[EDIT] **Verified working in Azure after adding ZUMO Version Header**
deployed the web api to azure and tried to call my web api endpoint and received a bad request error. It turns out it required an additional header for the version

```
'ZUMO-API-VERSION', '2.0.0'
```

I added the header and it worked.

Tried the local call again with the version header but still getting 401.

All I can assume is the OWIN middleware is not receiving the token probably due to a config problem - need some transparency into the pipeline to test some of these theories - not sure the best way to do that

Not sure where to look next in solving this.

[EDIT] **OWIN Pipeline Authenticate stage Hook**
OK - figured how to set up the equivalent to asp.net pipeline event handlers in OWIN - in my startup file I added this code to execute when the Authenticate stage is reached

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            return next.Invoke();
        });
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

Added a breakpoint and when the debugger stops I can see that in the call stack
that the Azure App Service Middleware in in the pipeline

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware
<Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication.AppServiceAuthenticationOptions>
.Invoke(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context)
```

**Confirmed OWINContext.Request.Headers Contains the Correct Auth Token**

Looking in the debugger the token is indeed in the Context.Request.Headers collection at the Authenticate stage of the OWIN pipeline and it has the correct value. For some reason still receiving the 401 status

I doubly checked the value I am using for the SigningKey - copied from the  WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY value in Azure.

[EDIT] **Debugging with source and exception being thrown in ValidateIdentity**

```
AppServiceAuthenticationHandler.ValidateIdentity
```

Downloaded source v1.1.157.1, loaded symbols from symbolsource but those are marked as 1.0.157.1 and visual studio is complaining that the source is different than when the module was built. Because of this I cannot step through the code to see the exception that is being caught.

[EDIT]**Built and Referenced v1.1.157.1 DLL - exception type now visible**

In the ValidateIdentity method when it calls

```
options.TokenHandler.TryValidateLoginToken
```

The following exception is thrown

```
"Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' 
from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.0.0.127,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."
```

[EDIT] **Finally found and fixed the issue**

There was an issue posted on GitHub for IdentityServer having to do with a breaking change with a nuget package - going from v4 -> v5 of System.IdentityModel.TokensJwt package.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3017

I downgraded my install to v4.0.x and it fixed the exception and also fixed the 401 errors I was seeing when running locally.

All is good now

Comment: Glad to hear it. We'll try to see what's up with the symbolsource issue and maybe we can do something to make these errors easier to detect.

Comment: I downgraded the System.IdentityModel.TokensJwt from 5.1.0 to 4.0.3.308261200 and now it works locally for me too. a lot of thanks for the provided solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct app settings for `authSigningKey`, `authAudience`, and `authIssuer` in your web.config?

FYI -- a good writeup of the setup is here in case you haven't stumbled upon it yet: http://www.systemsabuse.com/2015/12/04/local-debugging-with-user-authentication-of-an-azure-mobile-app-service/

Comment: I did see that article - it was helpful in setting it up to start but checked my settings based on it and all looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Is your localhost serving https traffic?
If a controller is decorated with [Authorize] it will require that the request/response occurs over https.

If you're targeting http://localhost, [Authorize] will cause a 302 to https://localhost.

This 302 can break the auth process. The solution would be to serve https locally, point your client to the appropriate port (my box uses :44300), and try it out again.

Also, make sure any relevant redirect URLs go to the https:// version of the URLs you're using.

Comment: yes - I am running localhost under https port 443 using a development cert